# How can I increase PHP memory limit in Plesk?

Tags: php

A client has given me a Plesk account to install his PHP app in, but the PHP memory limit is only 32M and I'd like to increase it. I tried to find this setting on the admin panel but couldn't :(

Answer (score 2):

You may adjust that value via .htaccess file.

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

Comment: nice, didn't know this was possible!

Comment: Unless your Plesk hosting company has disabled .htaccess (some do), it should work just fine.  Make a phpinfo(); page in the same directory as the new .htaccess file to see if the change has taken effect.

Comment: As mentioned by Embreau, this doesn't work if Fast-CGI is enabled, but editing the main php.ini works in that case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to update it on the control panel.

What you need to do is to create a file called :
vhost.conf

This file must be located in :

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf/
```

Inside this file, add (and change domain.com) :

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/>
php_value memory_limit 64M
</Directory>
```

As root, run the following :

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=domain.com
```

Restart Apache

Please note that if you use Fast-CGI this won't work, you would need to change it within the main php.ini.

EDIT: Added path to vhost.conf file

Comment: This is (almost definitely) a shared hosting server.  Rashal won't have the access to run that command.  I agree however, that your answer would work perfectly.

Comment: Being a shared server, he will have to ask his web hosting company.

Answer (score 1):

I use plesk 10 on my own shared Linux server and this works:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

Makes life easy because you can just do it where a script really should take up lots of RAM. Might need some changes depending on your server but for me it runs out of the box.

Comment: Just to clarify: This is a PHP statement, and you can just add it to your PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your admin panel allows you to access this file, but the usual way to increase PHP memory limit is by changing the memory_limit option in the php.ini file.